# How to replace a single page in a pdf using another pdf in linux?

Tags: linux, pdf

I want to find out the easiest way to replace a single page in a multiple page PDF with another single page PDF in Linux. What tool is best for this?

Currently I do it like this:

1. split pdf to single pages using [pdfsam](https://pdfsam.org/)
2. replace the pages that I want to replace
3. merge them using pdfsam
4. use ghostscript to force the page size as same

Any better way?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You could use the PDF Toolkit [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/):

Example:

```
pdftk A=inA.pdf B=inB.pdf cat A1-12 B3 A14-end output out1.pdf
```

The output consists of the first 12 pages of `inA.pdf`, followed by page 3 of `inB.pdf` and then pages 14 until end of `inA.pdf`.

Many Linux distributions provide a PDFtk package you can download and install using their package manager.

Comment: Thanks!  Note, A= and B= must be uppercase.  When I tried lowercase pdftk though a= was part of the filename.

Comment: Didn't work for me:
`
pdftk A=./inA.pdf B=./inB.pdf A1-4 B1 A6-end output out.pdf
Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   A1-4
Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   B1
Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   A6-end
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
` - I used qpdf and worked.

Comment: @azbarcea: the `cat` is missing. The complete command: `pdftk A=./inA.pdf B=./inB.pdf cat A1-4 B1 A6-end output out.pdf`. While `qpdf` certainly has its merits, `pdftk` allows additional rotation parameters for the `cat` operation. Try `pdftk --help`

Comment: Note that pdftk is hasn't been updated since 2013

Comment: This will not preserve bookmarks. As a workaround, you can use `dump_data` (check the docs) to dump bookmarks into a text file, and `update_info` to push those bookmarks to your output pdf file. The pdftk data dump only preserves page numbers, not offsets within the page. So a bookmark links to something at the bottom of the page after going through dump data and update info, the link will go to the top of the page.

Answer (score 36):

You could also use [qpdf](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf) which is open source:

Same example as the one in the [other response](https://superuser.com/a/611255/954052):

```
qpdf --empty --pages inA.pdf 1-12 inB.pdf 3 inA.pdf 14-z -- out1.pdf
```

Comment: You probably mean `inB.pdf` instead of `B.pdf`. This should probably be the accepted answer as `pdftk` is discontinued as far as I know.

Comment: I don't know if you can change the accepted answer after it is already set. However, I agree this is the better option as it is still very actively maintained. I also really like the fact that it offers an AppImage so you can use it without installing. :D

Answer (score 3):

Another very nice GUI alternative is [PDF Arranger](https://github.com/pdfarranger/pdfarranger).

Just load both PDF files, move the page where you want it, delete the page you don't want, and save.

Answer (score 1):

If you just wanted to replace the last page of a two-page pdf with another pdf (one-page), like me, but not trying to insert a page in between pages, it can be done like so:

```
sudo pdftk A=Doc1.pdf B=Doc2.pdf cat A1 B output DocEdited.pdf
```

Note:

- This will replace the last page in Doc1 with the page from Doc2;
- B is like B1-end; since Doc2 is a PDF of one page so B1 or B is the
  same;
- cat A1: Taking the first page from A (or Doc1).

Comment: There is no need to run pdftk as root. Please edit your answer to drop "sudo" from the command.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PDF Chain](https://pdfchain.sourceforge.io/).

PDF Chain is a graphical user interface for the [PDF Toolkit (PDFtk)](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/). The GUI supports all common features of the command line tool in a comfortable way.